# What is the type of an rspec test in Rails? a class or a module or a block or neither?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, rspec, tdd

I am looking at the body of an rspec file with *.rb suffix and can't quite figure out what type of object it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`describe` blocks are a class within the namespace `RSpec::ExampleGroups`.

`specify` blocks are an instance of `RSpec::Core::Example`

Comment: Thank you B. How would you describe/refer to the file example_spec.rb? Is "test" the right word?

Comment: No, it's a file. It has many specs. Some people say "test", but I think spec is more accurate.